# How to track email using 1 by 1 pixel image in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 10 for my email marketing project. I have embedded a 1 by 1 pixel png image in my email template blade file to track if email opened and clicked and created open and click columns in my database table. So after sending email when I view the email, the database open column is not updating with a value of 1. Also the image in email is broken. Whereas, the click column is working fine by updating with 1 when I click the link in the email.

**Email template code :**

```
<body class="antialiased">
        <img src="{{ route('track_open',['id' => $id]) }}" alt="{{$id}}">
        {{$id}}
        <a href=" {{ route('track_click',['url' => 'https://www.templatebench.com','id' => $id ]) }}" target="_blank">READ MORE</a>
    </body>
```

**Controller code :**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $mail = Campaign::find($request->id);
    $mail->open = 1;
    $res = $mail->save();
    return response(file_get_contents(public_path("1x1.png")));
}
```

**web.php route :**

```
Route::post('/images',[CampaignController::class,'index'])->name('track_open');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the image src request is going to be a GET request, but your route is for a POST request. Open the email in a web browser, with network tab open and verify the request details.

Comment: This will only work if the receivers allow to load additional content. I'll usually forbid it.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the image src request is going to be a GET request, but your route is for a POST request.

If you change your route to GET it should work.

```
Route::get('/images/{id}',[CampaignController::class,'index'])->name('track_open');
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed the route only as you said and worked.